# Browser showing uncompressed css

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I have this line in my config.rb:

```
output_style = :compressed
```

which after running compass with:

```
bundle exec compass watch
```

and after changing my .scss file, generates a compressed app.css file. I opened the generated file on the disk using a text editor to check, and the generated css was indeed compressed. However, after loading the page and opening the app.css file, I get an uncompressed file. I use this line to call the app.css in application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "app", :media => "screen, projector, print" %>
```

How is it possible that the css from the browser is not compressed? I am not using "compass-rails", but "compass" gem. I guess they are not the same thing? Perhaps this has something to do with config/environments ? This is all done in development. I am also positive that the browser loaded new css (I changed the background color, and the change was applied on refresh). Could it be that the compass is compiling css on the fly for each page load in development environment? Thanks.

Comment: Although I am not entirely sure, this seems to be more related to the assets pipeline than to compass IMHO.

Comment: @pootzko Does the generated `app.css` file placed under the `app/assets/stylesheets` dir?

Comment: @Domon - yes it's placed there